# Adding the same cell from multiple worksheets with python

Tags: python, sum, xlrd, worksheet, xlwt

I have a Python program with works great so far, However...... I need to sum all of the same cell position across 52 different worksheets now.

```
For example:   I have 52 sheets and need to sum cell D75 across all the sheets in my coversheet.
```

Mind you the coversheet is already made and I have no issues with that, i just need to determine how to incorporate the sum into  my coversheet.

CHEERS!!!

Comment: Are you ok with making a formula via `xlwt` somewhere inside the excel file and then just read it via `xlrd`?

Answer (score 0):

completely untested, let me know if you can't get this to work and I'll take a closer look

```
wb = open_workbook('simple.xls')
values = []
for s in wb.sheets(): #iterate over the sheets
    cell = sheet.cell(3,74) #D=3, need to offset 75 by 1 hence 74
    values.append(float(cell.value))
print sum(values)
```

also, this is a pretty good tutorial http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf